# Conform to protocl in extension, how to initialize properties?

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

I have the following protocol adapted from [one of Apple's examples](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit/providing_hands-free_app_control_with_intents):

```
protocol CurrentCounterProviding: NSObject {
    
    var intentHandler: IntentHandler {  get }
    
    @discardableResult
    func increaseCountIntent(counters: [CounterIntent]) -> IncreaseCountIntentResponse
    
}
```

I want to make my ViewModel conform to it, but the view model is used by multiple targets and I only want one of the targets to implement it. So I want to add the code to a separate file only loaded to a particular target, but I'm encountering some issues:

[image: code showing the error: invalid declaration of init]

Here's the code:

```
extension CounterViewModel : CurrentCounterProviding {
    var intentHandler : IntentHandler {
        get {
            return IntentHandler(increaseCounterProvider: self, currentCounters: [IntentHandler.counterToCounterIntent(counter: counter)])
        }
    }
    
    convenience init(counter: Counter, sound : Bool, showTotal: Bool, viewContext : NSManagedObjectContext) {
        self.init(counter: counter, sound : sound, showTotal: showTotal, viewContext : viewContext)
        AppIntentHandler.shared.currentIntentHandler = intentHandler

        
    }

    func increaseCountIntent(counters: [CounterIntent]) -> IncreaseCountIntentResponse {
          increaseCount()
          let message = accessibilityMessage(prefix: NSLocalizedString("Increased ", comment: "a11y"))
          return IncreaseCountIntentResponse.success(name: [counter.name ?? ""], totals: [message])
      }
}
```

The original code uses view controllers, while I'm using SwiftUI, so I'm trying to adapt the code with no luck.

Comment: This doesn't look related to the protocol (the error isn't referring to anything required by the protocol). It looks like you've implemented `CounterViewModel.init(counter:sound:showTotal:viewContext)` somewhere else (and are trying to call it). It can only be implemented one time. As written, your call to `self.init(...)` would be an infinite loop if this worked anyway. That said, modifying a global variable in an `init` of an unrelated class is a very fragile pattern. It's not clear what you're trying to achieve with this. The sample code you've linked doesn't do anything like that.

Comment: It's possible that you've missing the fact that UIKit's `viewDidAppear` is closely related to SwiftUI's `onAppear(perform:)`.

Comment: I tried implementing the protocol in the view, but then when I tried to assign the ‘intentHandler’ on ‘onAppear’, I get an error about self being immutable

Comment: You're probably misusing (or missing) `@State`, `@StateObject`, etc. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-user-interface-state